# Working with a database

Tags: database

I have an existing program for a bank account, the user can create an account then withdraw or deposit money to the account.  As a transaction is processed, labels are being used to show the current information such as (Beginning Balance, Transaction Fee, Withdrawal Amount, and Ending Balance).

Now, I need to be able to keep track of the transactions being processed in a SQL database.  I know how to add a database to the project and then set it up to display all of the data from the table in a gridview. This is assuming that I manually entered data into the table; however, the table should be blank when the program starts and as I process transactions, then the data should be written to the table.

How do I bind my existing fields (labels) to a datatable and send the text to the table.  The book that I have is all related to just displaying the data that is already in the table and I have been through a couple of tutorial online and they seem to be about the same subject.  I haven't found anything on how to do what I am looking for.

Can someone help me out here.  I don't mind references to other websites that might have the answer.

Thanks,
Susan

Comment: How are you currently storing the data? By "labels" do you mean a static HTML file?

Comment: -1: No language, no platform, no tools, no framework.  Really hard to provide any help with so little to go on.

Comment: A little more detail about the environment would be helpful. What language? Platform? Since you say it should be empty when the program starts, are you talking about an in-memory database?

Comment: And, Susan, we would all benefit if your subject line were more specific. There's probably 1000 questions here that this same subject line could fit!

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to go in to much more detail about your issue. Sounds like you have some fundamental set up issues with your tools, but you don't mention the tools, platform (OS), or database you are using. So, it's difficult for anyone to even point in a general direction, much less give any specific, relevant suggestions.